# jQuery Mobile Select Menu behaving improperly in panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a very strange problem, that is specific to my code, as I have tried stripping it down and putting it in a jsfiddle. I'm running jQuery 1.9.1 and JQM 1.4.2.

My JQM site is all pages loaded to one file, and uses the hashtag navigation. I have a set of selectmenus, one is just a regular one like:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="Panel" data-position="right" data-display="overlay">
    <select id="Select" data-native-menu="false">
        <option>Title</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

When I select an option, the app reloads and goes back to the start page. I also have the same issue with a multi select group.

I know there is not enough info in this post to get a good answer yet, but without uploading the entire source, I'm not sure what code will be of use in debugging this.

Comment: Updated my question, and added the versions.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. I thought It might be a _popup_ history issue, since non-native selectmenu is converted into a popup or dialog depending on viewport's height and number of options. Are you using any other plugin?

Comment: I am not. That was my thought, but now it's happening on a static page too, but not all of them do, just certain ones...and there is nothing different and no js tied to them.

Comment: The behavior is almost like submitting a form, but there is no form involved.

Comment: try setting history to false globally `$.mobile.popup.prototype.options.history = false;` as in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CgLeA/ `mobileinit` should be placed before jqm.js in head.

Comment: That appears to have fixed it. But why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56675/discussion-between-omar-and-user3669154).